# How do I find the revision of a lost commit?

Tags: git

I checked the reflog and .git/logs, but I couldn't find the revision of the commit I wanted.

I think it's probably because the repository has been newly cloned. Unfortunately, there is no local repository that I worked on before...

I think it's stored in .git as tree or blob, is there any way to find it neatly? I know the file name.

Currently, there is nothing in .git/objects and Only one pack file exists *.idx and *. in .git/objects/pack and I have all the objects visible through the git unpack-objects command.

Comment: How was the commit lost?

Comment: I did a hard reset and force-push and immediately removed my local repository via the rm -rf command. And I realized that everything was wrong.

Comment: Where is the remote?

Comment: It's in github, a private repository.

Comment: you really think that this command: "rm -rf command"  is only doing harm to others, and not to your ?

Comment: I think can solve it if find all blobs related to a specific file, is there any way?

Comment: where do your think those blobs where stored ?

Comment: I think it's stored in .git/objects, and I'm not sure. Also, I don't think it's possible to check the objects one by one through the git-cat-file-p commands.

Comment: Keep on doing this research it might reveal that `rm -rf` is a bad option (most of the times )

Comment: `I think it's stored in .git/objects` but you removed your .git/objecs, it's not longer there, so where do you think it's stored? https://superuser.com/questions/116153/rescuing-files-and-commits-from-no-branch-in-git https://medium.com/git-tips/githubs-reflog-a9ff21ff765f

Comment: @KamilCuk wow... I solved it with the medium link you gave me. Thank you very much.